# Laravel 5 can't reach custom class function

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I have a question about Laravel 5. I made a new directory and file in the app directory.

```
App
    Helpers
        weather.php
    Http
        Controllers
            test.php
```

I want to access the function in weather.php but it doesn't work.

Weather.php

```
namespace App\Helpers

class Weather {

    public function test() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

Test.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function bla() {
        return \App\Helpers\Weather\test();
    }
}
```

I get an error that the class is not found. Hope someone can help me because I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after creating this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line is not correct:

```
return \App\Helpers\Weather\test();
```

if you want to call the `test` method you should first of all create an instance of the object `Weather`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function bla()
    {
        $w = new \App\Helpers\Weather();

        return $w->test();
    }
}
```

Instead, if you want to call the method directly on the class, you should make this method static:

```
class Weather {

    public static function test() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

and call it this way:

```
public function bla()
{
    return \App\Helpers\Weather::test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.0 and 5.1 you no longer need to run `composer dump-autoload` because the new PSR-4 takes care of that.

I think this is the proper way to do it:

In Weather.php - NB: File name should be `Weather.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers

class Weather {
   public function test() {
      return "A";
   }
}
```

In TestController.php

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Helpers\Weather;

 class TestController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Weather $weather){
        $this->weather = $weather;
    }

    public function bla() {
        return $this->weather->test();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `weather.php` has a lowercase w which should be uppercase. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your helper class should be added to `autoload` section `composer.json`. Like,

```
autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Http/Helpers/weather.php"
    ]
},
```